# asp.net web api documentation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a web api project and an admin panel(web project).

I want only the admin users can access the web api documentation.

The web api and admin project are hosted as virtual directories in IIS.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I have already wrote the code set principal in `gloabl.asax` of admin project and below is the code:

```
try
{
    //let us take out the username now                
    string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
    string roles = "Admin";

    //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
        new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
}
```

Please assist.

Comment: You need to set the principal for authentication and authorization. Please read more here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Does the Api documentation render from a html-file, use login window. If the documentation renders from a web api controller use the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] ontop of the controller.

Comment: API project is hosted at : http://localhost:1000/api/Help and admin project is hosted at : http://localhost:1000/admin. Both admin and api are hosted on different virtual directory how can I share the principal between 2 directories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cookie authentication in your web api project first. You can share the cookie between 2 applications. Make sure the Cookie Names are identical in each application.
Please refer to http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SharingAuthorizationCookiesBetweenASPNET4xAndASPNETCore10.aspx